# most efficient way to UPDATE a table using critera from other tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

What is the most efficient/fastest way to update a table that requires foreign keys (to other tables) in the criteria?

I normally do it this way:

```
UPDATE table1 WHERE table1_id in (SELECT table1_id FROM table2 WHERE whatever)
```

But I'm trying to figure out if there is a more efficient way that avoids the subquery.

The reason I want to know is because I JUST yesterday learned that it's possible to delete without a subquery like this:

```
DELETE t1 FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.table1_id = t2.table1_id 
WHERE whatever
```

But I can't figure out how to apply the same JOIN technique to an UPDATE statement

Comment: You've tagged this for both SQL Server and Oracle.  The two support different syntax-- the syntax that you posted would not be valid in Oracle (though Oracle may support a very similar approach depending on the definition of `t1` and `t2`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

**MS-SQL:**

```
UPDATE t
SET column_id = t2.column_id
FROM table1 t
JOIN table2 t2 ON t.table1_id = t.table2_id 
WHERE whatever
```

**Oracle:**

```
UPDATE (
    SELECT table1.value as OLD, table2.CODE as NEW
    FROM table1
    JOIN table2 ON table1.value = table2.DESC
    WHERE anything
) t
SET t.OLD = t.NEW
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE (
  SELECT t1.*
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.table1_id = t2.table1_id 
  WHERE whatever
) t
SET t.col = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can perform a bulk update based on a cursor that can fetch from unlimited amount of tables. This is the fastest way to update.

```
declare
    cursor cur_cur
    IS
    select t1.rowid row_id, t2.column1, t2.column2
    FROM table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.table1_id = t2.table1_id 
    WHERE whatever
    order by row_id
    ;

    type type_rowid_array is table of rowid index by binary_integer;
    type type_column1_array is table of table1.column1%type;
    type type_column2_array is table of table1.column2%type;

    arr_rowid type_rowid_array;
    arr_column1 type_column1_array;
    arr_column2 type_column2_array;

    v_commit_size number := 10000;

begin
    open cur_cur;

    loop
        fetch cur_cur bulk collect into arr_rowid, arr_column1, arr_column2 limit v_commit_size;

        forall i in arr_rowid.first .. arr_rowid.last
            update table1 tab
            SET    tab.column1 = arr_column1(i)
            ,      tab.column2 = arr_column2(i)
            where  tab.rowid = arr_rowid(i)
            ;

        commit;
        exit when cur_cur%notfound;

    end loop;

    close cur_cur;
    commit;

exception
  when others
    then rollback;
         raise_application_error(-20000, 'Fout bij uitvoeren update van table1(column1,column2) - '||sqlerrm);

end;
```

Comment: Do you have a reference for this being faster than an `update` in the database?  I can't find any, and I would expect cursors to be slower because their use requires sending data back to the application, out of the database.  Also, the database can perform an update in parallel, and I think cursors would prevent this.

Comment: the pl/sql bulk update performs a lot faster than a normal update. Just test it out :) (Although maybe a single record update might be fastest using a normal update statement)